# net/ftp invalid argument error

Tags: ruby

I have a relatively simple script that was working. Nothing in the script changed and I'm using ruby 1.8.6.

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net:: FTP.new(ip)
ftp.login(user=name,passwd=pass)
ftp.chdir(pathHere)
ftp.gettextfile('onhandapt.txt', File.basename('onhandapt.txt'))
ftp.close
```

I know from running through the steps in irb that I can login successfully, and even issue a ftp.list command to get the current directory, but ftp.chdir is where the scripts fails. In irb, the ftp.chdir command yields 'nil'. Double checked the path on the server.

The script produces this error: 
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:211:in `readline': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:211:in`getline'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:221:in `getmultiline'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:235:in`getresp'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:251:in `voidresp'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:274:in`voidcmd'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:290:in`sendport'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:298:in `makeport'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:329:in`transfercmd'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:421:in `retrlines'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`synchronize'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:419:in `retrlines'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:518:in`gettextfile'

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you tried a manual ftp-client to check that you can actually can go into the target directory? I.e. that you're not dealing with some sort of permission issue or similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure pathHere contains a valid pathname and not set to nil

Comment: path is correct. In my script, I actually issue ftp.chdir('live/www'). in irb, I can step when I issue ftp.chdir('live'), it reports nil.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. We had some office network changes. I now need to use passive mode, which can be set with this command: `ftp.passive=true`